# Change width of child div element using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an element in my html with this markup:

```
<div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" role="tabpanel" style="width: 98px; display: block;">
```

I would like to know how to remove the width attribute using jQuery

Comment: what do you mean by remove?

Comment: you want to change width or remove the attribute width?

Comment: `.css('width', 'auto')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove any inline css attribut with this code :

```
$(selector).css("attribut", "");
```

So, in your case, use this :

```
$(".ui-accordion-content").css("width", "");
```

Comment: You would probably be better off in the long run if you can add the width to a css class instead.

$('.ui-accordion-content-active').removeClass('customWidth');

Comment: Not sure why people would downvote a corret answer. Additional note: Doing so you can also enter new values for your css attribute.

Comment: Why other people all propose to change the value, when bodzilla ask to remove the value ...

Comment: @Bazaim Yes I want to remove the attribute completely, therefore this solution works best.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you,

```
$(".ui-accordion-content").css('width', 'auto;');
```

This will make the `div` to default width. `i.e 100%`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width to be auto.....

```
$("selector").css('width','auto');
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
.css('width', 'auto')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
$(".ui-accordion-content").css('width', 'auto');
```

or assign a ID to div id='myDivId'

```
$("#myDivId").css('width', 'auto');
```